# "MessageEmbed field values may not be empty" problem in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord bot in node.js and keep getting this problem. I'm trying to make a help command but i want to try to make sure embeds and stuff work before doing the command, and i keep getting this weird error. I put two code samples, one is the code for the command, and one is the code for what makes the commands actually work. Can someone help?

```
module.exports = {
name: 'command',
description: "Commands for the bot!",
execute(message, args, Discord) {
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#304281')
    .setTitle('Commands')
    .setURL('https://discord.com/terms')
    .setDescription('Showing commands..')
    .addFields(
        {name: 'Rule 1', value: ''},
        {name: 'Rule 1', value: ''},
        {name: 'Rule 1', value: ''}
    )
    .setImage('https://blog.logomyway.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/discord-mascot.png')
    .setFooter('Bot created by John Adams#7337');

    message.channel.send(newEmbed);
}
```

}

```
client.on('message', message => {
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'ping'){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    
} else if (command === 'botinfo'){
    client.commands.get('botinfo').execute(message, args);

} else if (command === 'test'){
    client.commands.get('test').execute(message, args);

} else if (command === 'command'){
    client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
}
```

});

And here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432
if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
            ^
```

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
at Function.normalizeField (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
at C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:452:14
at Array.map ()
at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\commands\command.js:11:10)
at Client. (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:39:40)
at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Chunko\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}

Comment: Pretty self explanatory, you have an empty field value, look at `{name: 'Rule 1', value: ''},`

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple error and you have made a very blunder mistake.

In Discord.js Embed When you are adding fields in the embed you are expected to add to parameters in a field 1. `Title Or the name of the field` and 2. `The content or the value of the field`.

But as in your case you have kept the second parameter aka the `value` is empty. So it remove this error instead of `{name: 'Rule 1', value: ''}` you should do it `{name: 'Rule 1', value: 'Your rule here do not keep it empty'}`.